# How do I search through a property for a particular value?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following Entity Framework models:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Email> EmailAddresses { get; set; }
}

public class Email
{
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

I want to be able to query these and get back the Person or Persons that have a particular email address.

Is this possible? I know if the list were just a list of strings it would be something like:

`PersonRepository.Where(x => x.Emails.Contains("myemail@host.com"))` but I'm stuck here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is still possible, just needs one more step:

```
PersonRepository.Where(x => x.EmailAddresses
                             .Any(a => a.Address == "myemail@host.com"))
```

Comment: I was going to suggest using that.

Comment: @GrantWinney, right, sorry, have no idea how I overlooked that